# bootstrap 5 how to close the whole menu when click on the link or click outside on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using `BootStrap 5` to build my page

I have a `NavBar Menu` with links

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent pt-0 pb-0">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand pt-0 pb-0 me-0" href="#home">Salimi<span>Me</span></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler border-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#timeline">Education</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <a class="top-btn text-decoration-none d-inline-block" href="#">Download CV</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

what i try to do is when the user click on the link i want the whole meu to close and the user get the section he want

also if he click outside the menu the menu close if it's open

How to close the whole NavBar Menu when i click on a link inside or i click outside on the page?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />



    
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <style></style>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                id="navbarDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>

  
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't want a dropdown menu inside the navbar menu my menu have a links when i click on the link i want to close the whole menu or when i click outside on the page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).